# How to make just audio flutter handler always play stream from live position, not from saved position after pause?

Tags: icecast, just-audio, audiobuffer, audio-service

After pausing icecast radio player app with just audio and audio service packages from Ryan Heise, I wait a little and tap play again, the stream continues to play from saved position with data in buffers, then suddenly (I think when buffers are empty) changes to live position in stream. It is possible for me to clear buffers on pause/stop in my Audio Handler? Or should I use another approach?

Comment: Can you try `player.seek(null)` to force it to immediately seek to the head of the livestream? Also which platform is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried player.seek(null), but it needed more work, so I decided to not use it. We haven't encountered this behaviour anymore since a month or so. It works fine now. Thanks!